# Invoke custom broadcastreceiver for another app

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have 2 apps, App1 and App2

In App1, manifest file has BroadcastReceiverIncoming defined as below.

```
<receiver android:name="packagename.BroadcastReceiverIncoming"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="packagename.BroadcastReceiverIncoming" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiverIncoming is defined in App1.

Now in App2, I am calling this to invoke broadcast receiver but it's now working somehow?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("packageName", "packagename.BroadcastReceiverIncoming");
intent.setAction("packagename.BroadcastReceiverIncoming");
appContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Even with line 2 commented/uncommented, it does not invoke BroadcastReceiverIncoming.

Through adb if I call `adb shell am broadcast -n packageName/packagename.BroadcastReceiverIncoming`
BroadcastReceiverIncoming is being invoked correctly in App1.

Answer (score 2):

I have this working as below:

```
    myServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent data) {
            if (data.getAction().equals(POLayer.SVC_INTENT)) {
                final String alias = data.getStringExtra("alias");
                final String command = data.getStringExtra("action");
                if (command.equals("dosomething")) {
                    new DoSomethingTask().execute( alias );
                }
                             }
                     }
             };

  ....

  onCreate:
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(POLayer.SVC_INTENT);
    filter.addAction(POLayer.ANOTHER_INTENT);
    this.registerReceiver(this.myServiceReceiver, filter);
```

In the sender:

```
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction( SVC_INTENT );
                i.putExtra( "alias", theAlias );
                i.putExtra( "action", "dosomething" );
                this.sendBroadcast( i );
```

The only difference I see is that I'm not relying on the package/component names, but rather define my own ACTIONs. Also, all names are case-sensitive, so you might want to check on packageName vs. packagename.

Comment: I am talking specifically about invoking custom broadcast receiver in another app.

Comment: And I've posted code specifically showing you how I do that. The sender and receiver are in two different packages/apps.

Comment: Thanks,Instead of registering receiver through registerReceiver, I have declared it in the manifest.
Should it not invoke Receiver automatically?

Comment: It *should*. But you say it doesn't?

Comment: Yes somehow it's not invoked through code in App2?
If I run adb command to send Broadcast, it does work.
Any help :(

Comment: The only difference I see in our senders is that I don't specify the class. Scrap line 2 and see if that works.

Comment: Nope.. does not work even if I comment line 2 i.e. setClassName.. 
Not sure if I am doing some silly mistake :(..

Comment: Well, when all fails... double-check the spelling. Sorry, mate.

Comment: packageName vs. packagename. ;)

Comment: Pretty sure.. checked everything again :((

Comment: @andjav -- post your problem. It looks like "awesome" just got the spelling mixed up.